# I'm passing a tuple out of an Elm app via a port. What type of object will JavaScript receive?

Tags: javascript, types, interop, elm

A tuple doesn't seem to map directly to any specific type of object in JS. What will it translate to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will translate to a fixed-length, mixed-type JavaScript array.

From the [Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html#customs-and-border-protection):

- **Booleans and Strings** – both exist in Elm and JS!
- **Numbers** – Elm ints and floats correspond to JS numbers
- **Lists** – correspond to JS arrays
- **Arrays** – correspond to JS arrays
- **Tuples** – correspond to fixed-length, mixed-type JS arrays
- **Records** – correspond to JavaScript objects
- **Maybes** – Nothing and Just 42 correspond to null and 42 in JS

Answer (score 0):

Note: that sending `null` into a port will result in a `Unit` or `()`.